# How to assign a inputted string to a variable ONLY when a button is clicked?

Tags: python, variables, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Problem:
I am making a little GUI program using tkinter to automatically backup all files of a given extension from an provided source location to provided destination location. To take the source and destination locations from the user, I added tkinter entry widgets with their respective CONFIRM buttons, which when clicked, should assign the text in entry box to the respective variables.

What I tried:
I am making the code in separate functions and so theres a separate function for creating widgets that get the soucre location, destination location, extensions, etc. In the functions, I definied other function (`buttonClick`) which is the command for the button widget. The source, destination variables are preset to empty strings. The function  is like so:

```
def buttonClick():
    global destination
    destination = destinationEntry.get()
```

But this destination value which is assigned here is not usable outside this function, even after declaring it global. `destinationEntry` is the entry widget to get the finale location of files.

Edit: The minimal code->

```
import tkinter as tk
source = 'example'

def sourceWidgets(master):
    labelFrame = tk.LabelFrame(master)
    labelFrame.grid(column=0, row=0)

    sourceEntry = tk.Entry(labelFrame, width=28)
    sourceEntry.grid(column=0, row=0)

    def buttonClick():
        global source
        source = sourceEntry.get()

    confirmButton = tk.Button(labelFrame, text=' Confirm ', command=buttonClick)
    confirmButton.grid(column=1, row=0)

def main():
    window = tk.Tk()
    sourceWidgets(window)
    print(source)
    window.mainloop()
    print(source)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [mcve]. WIth just the code you posted I can say with certainty that `destination` can be used outside of the function.

Comment: @BryanOakley edited OP to have that. While the window is not closed, only the first print call is called, but as soon as i close the window, the other print call is called and the entered string gets printed. I want to the program to change the source variables value without closing the window.

Comment: Your code works fine. When I click on the `confirm` button, the value is changed as expected. It won't show up in the first `print` statement because that statement occurs before I click on the button. If you add another button that prints out the value, you'll see that it has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `window.mainloop()` your programm is in this loop, and only in this loop, as long as your window is open. So the first print statement is called even before your window opens, and the second one is called when the window is closed.

You have to work with the variabel **inside** of the mainloop().
For example print the value inside the `buttonClick()` function.

Another approach is to use `tk.StringVar()` as text_variable of the entry field and trace the variable. That way you can write a callback function that is called every time the variable changes.

Comment: Oh. If thats the case, I will have to reformat the main code. Thanks for help!